# Sharing Android text with the icon of my app

Tags: android, share, thumbnails

Is it possible to share a text with the icon of my app similiar to this?

[image]

Because i've try to do this but it works with plain text , but when i try with an image it share the entire image, but i just want a little thumbnail.
That's my actual code:

```
Intent intent2=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            intent2.setType("image/*"); 
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,random); 
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File(Image));
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path );
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent2, "Share via"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: I want to use the icon of my app, not an extarnal image.

Comment: so try this:
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package/drawable/fileName");

sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + C.PROJECT_PATH + "/drawable/" + R.drawable.icon_to_share);

Comment: I've added your code like this:
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.techappstudios.randomquotes" + "/drawable/"+ R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,random + "\n"+" By Random Quotes"); 
    intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);


But it will share it like a full imege, not a thubnails...

Comment: ok, use this decoder:
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);